# codeigniter create response array object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the code below, but the result of the json response doesn't match

```
public function tes_get(){
        $kode= $this->M_mymodel->tbl_kode('302'); // row
        $res = array();
        foreach ($kode as $key=> $value) {
            $win = $this->M_mymodel->db_aa('302'); //row_array
            $res = $this->M_mymodel->db_bb('302','LOSE'); //row_array
            $res['data'][] = array(
                'win' => $win['menang'],
                'lose' =>$res['kalah']
            );
        } 
        $response =  $this->set_response($res,200); 
    }
```

Below is the result of the response from the code I made above

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "win": "2",
            "lose": "11"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to make json response like below?

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "win": "2",
        }
        {
            "lose": "11"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/rk589SBpSgKhZsFC5zSOOw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
$res['data'][] = array(
    array('win' => $win['menang']),
    array('lose' =>$res['kalah'])
);
```